# Inspect Configuration and Control Register in ARM with GDB

Tags: android, gdb, arm

Is there any way to see Configuration and Control Register while debugging a code through GDB? I am debugging an application on ARM v7 and I need to see value of this register. I also want to know how in general you can set value of this register?

Comment: That's a system register and can't be accessed from user mode. OS sets that for you and should provide you some convenient ways to get what you want from those registers.

Comment: Thanks, I think they must be set via header files, do you know how to set them?

Comment: It is generally done by in inline assembly. See mrc/mcr instructions.

Comment: @auselen Should I expect to see mcr instruction in disassembled code?